# sprintf_s throwing buffer-overflow error in C++

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, printf

I have a method that takes in the parameter as input `CString inputString`.

```
DWORD blockLength;
blockLength = inputString.GetLength();

PBYTE defaultBuffer = NULL; 
defaultBuffer = new unsigned char[blockLength + 1];

sprintf_s(reinterpret_cast<char*>(defaultBuffer), (blockLength + 1), "%s", (LPCSTR)inputString);
```

I get the error that the function might be able to write outside bounds of the allocated memory (on `sprintf_s` line) which could corrupt data.

Comment: If you have to cast, you are likely doing it wrong. `CString` (assuming this is ATL/MFC code) stores either `char` or `wchar_t` code units. If it is the latter, you are in for a fun ride (for some definition of *"fun"*).

Comment: If `inputString` contains Unicode characters instead of Ansi characters, `inputString.GetLength()` may not be the same length as `strlen((char*)inputString)`.  Do the conversion first, then get the length of the converted data.

Comment: @IInspectable - I'm sorry but I didn't get your point exactly. What change would you suggest code-wise?

Comment: @RemyLebeau - If I make the change: dwBlockLen = strlen((char*)src);
I get the error - "No suitable function to convert from CString to char exist."

Comment: @user2769790: Your `sprintf_s` code uses `(LPCSTR)inputString`. `CString` does not have `char*` or `LPCSTR` (aka `const char*`) conversion operators, it only has an `LPCTSTR` (aka `const  TCHAR*`) conversion operator. So the only way your code compiles is if you are compiling for ANSI/MBCS where `TCHAR` is `char`, not for Unicode where `TCHAR` is `wchar_t`. So, use `LPCSTR` instead of `char*` when calling `strlen()`

Comment: Remove the `(LPCSTR)` cast, and call [`CString::GetString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class#getstring) instead. Also, since you are using `sprintf_s`, you should be explicit about your `CString`'s character encoding. `CStringA` is the matching string type. It's also not at all clear, why you are `new`-ing an `unsigned char` array, just to then cast it to `char*` (or why you aren't using a `std::vector<char>` to begin with).

Comment: @RemyLebeau - strlen((LPCSTR*)inputString) did fix the problem.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - you mentioned that CString does not have char* or LPCSTR (aka const char*) conversion operators, it only has an LPCTSTR. So why did we not use LPCTSTR, and used LPCSTR?

Comment: @user2769790: because you clearly don't understand how `TCHAR` actually works, and you just picked whatever happened to work for you. `sprintf_s` expects only `const char*` input for the `%s` specifier.  `(LPCSTR)inputString` will compile only if the project is set to ANSI/MBCS (`TCHAR=char`), it will NOT compile if the project is set to Unicode (`TCHAR=wchar_t`). `LPCTSTR` and `LPCSTR` map to the same type in ANSI/MBCS, they do not map to the same type in Unicode.

Comment: @user2769790: `(LPCSTR*)` is not a valid type-cast for `inputString`. You need to use `(LPCSTR)` instead (no `*`) (you should be using `(LPCTSTR)` instead, since that is what `CString` actually expects). In C++ you really should be using `static_cast` instead of C-style casting: `static_cast<LPCSTR>(inputString)`. In any case, `LPCTSTR` will not work for `sprintf_s` if you compile for Unicode. Consider using `_stprintf_s` instead, which operates on `TCHAR` strings.  Or, with `sprintf_s`, you can use `%ls` or `%S`  for `wchar_t*` input, and `%s` for `char*` input.

Comment: I'm sorry. I typed it wrong. I actually used strlen((LPCSTR)inputString) and that worked. bot the *
Thanks a lot for the explanation @RemyLebeau

Comment: Hey @RemyLebeau, you mentioned earlier "If inputString contains Unicode characters instead of Ansi characters, inputString.GetLength() may not be the same length as strlen((char*)inputString)"..
MSDN says GetLength gets the number of bytes, which should be what strlen returns. Can you please elaborate a little bit on why to use strlen instead of GetLength?

Comment: @user2769790 `GetLength()` and `strlen()` are the same thing when `CString` holds `char` elements. They are not the same thing when it holds `wchar_t` elements instead.

Comment: So this is basically to cover the case for Unicode where TCHAR is wchar_t. If in case we don't use Unicode, then we can keep "blockLength = inputString.GetLength();"? but since we need to do casting in this case, we used strlen((LPCSTR)inputString). 
Am I getting that right?